# Speed Up IReport, Windows

Tags: ireport

i´m using IReport 4.5.0 on my Win7 64Bit.

Previous Version does it also.
JavaVersion:

```
java version "1.7.0_02"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_02-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.0-b10, mixed mode)
```

`iReport` is horrible slow in the "DESIGNER" mode.

Selecting any Item will delay the marking of the selected item for 10Seconds up to 20seconds...

Using a Picture (f.e. 16x16 PNG Icon in TitleBand) will increase that behaviour.

Any Idea for Speed Up the `iReport`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The environment variable to set is `MAVEN_OPTS`, for example `MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx1024m`. The `maxmem` configuration in the pom only applies when you set the compiler plugin to fork  `javac` into a new JVM. Otherwise the plugin runs inside the same VM as Maven and thus within the memory passed on the command line via the `MAVEN_OPTS`.

To set MAVEN_OPTS under Windows 7:

1. **Right click** on My Computer and select **Properties**
2. Click the **Advanced System Settings** link located in the left navigation of System Properties to display the **Advanced System Properties**
3. Go to the **Advanced** tab and **click** the **Environment Variables** button located at the bottom of the **Advanced System Properties** configuration window
4. Create a **New** user variable, set the **Variable name** to MAVEN_OPTS and set the **Variable value** to `-Xmx1024m` (or more)

Open a new command window and run `mvn`.